Automate a large SQL query and have it export the results in to a csv formatted file?
I was provided a large SQL query that essentially grabs results from multiple different tables and dbo's. The query has if statements, variables, and temporary tables involved. I am trying to figure out the simplest way to automate running this query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio then exporting the results of the table to a formatted CSV w/ headers.
I started by trying to have powershell run this query for me, but since the DB doesn't use Windows Authentication, I kept running in to permission issues with grabbing the query from a file on the network, authenticating with the SQL server, then writing to a location on the network since I only specified DB credentials (It wouldn't write since the DB Credentials don't have permissions on the network) and I couldn't find how to specify what credentials to use for saving/writing opposed to running the query. One thought I had was to just give permissions to a specific domain service account in the DB and authenticate that way but I didn't try that route yet.
After I ran into credential errors, I decided to look into other options. I started messing around with Python and I got to the point where I could write a simple SQL query and have it do what I needed, it would authenticate to the DB, open the file and run the query, then export the results to a csv. I thought everything was good until I changed the file to the SQL Query I was provided and I ran in to some issues. My first problem was a 'NoneType' could not be iterated problem which I believe I solved by breaking down the query into separate statements designated by a semicolon and having it run through a for loop but this didn't work either. I was getting errors about variables not be able to be turned into strings or something like that. After "researching" the issue (google) someone mentioned to just take the semicolons out, this fixed that error but I then realized it broke my python code because I was no longer able to specify one statement at a time. So currently I kind of have an amalgamation of multiple different code that essentially does similar things, but I haven't been able to put together the right pieces to make this work.
Here's what I currently have, note a lot of it is commented out as I try to figure out how to make this work:
connectionString = odbc.connect(
    'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    'Server=SERVER;'
    'Database=DB;'
    'UID=USER;'
    'PWD=PASSWORD;'
)



# Open and read the query file as a single buffer
fd = open('largeQuery.sql', 'r')
# Saves query file in sqlFile variable
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()

# all SQL commands from query (split on ';')
#sqlCommands = filter(None, sqlFile.split(';'))

# Execute every command from the query file
#for command in sqlCommands:
    # This will skip and report errors
    # For example, if the tables do not yet exist, this will skip over
    # the DROP TABLE commands
    #try:
        # Executes each command from query file that has been filtered by ;
        #connectionString.execute(command)
    
    #except Exception as inst:
        #print("Command skipped: ", inst)

#query = pd.read_sql_query(sqlFile, connectionString)

# Read the sql file and execute the query
#with open('largeQuery.sql', 'r') as query:
    #DF = pd.read_sql_query(query.read(),connectionString)

#DF = pd.DataFrame(query)

outname = 'Data.csv'
outdir = './dir'
if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir)

fullname = os.path.join(outdir, outname)   

# Outputs Query results to CSV located in file path location
#DF.to_csv(fullname) #+ datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y') + '.csv', index = False)

connectionString.close()

I also realized as I was using the for loop and filtering each statement by breaking it up into semicolons, I had no idea how to grab the results from the query after it was fully executed. I feel like I'm really close to figuring this out but I have absolutely no experience in Python and barely have experience in large SQL queries like the one I was provided. Any information would be helpful such as, am I even on the right path or using the right tool for the job?!

Does this answer your question?

There shouldn't be any problems exporting stuff by using powershell, see: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/exporting-data-with-powershell for instance. Using python and dataframes is overkill

Have you checked into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services

I would think about simplification of this via creation of a stored procedure that did all your multi-command SQL. Alternatively, using the multi=True cursor parameter. In either case, I would directly write tuples via the csv package rather than use pandas.

Create a stored procedure and put the query there. Run the query via SQL Agent.

You can use in PS invoke-sqlcmd (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) and then save results with Export-CSV (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.4)

Thanks for all the comments, I kind of used an amalgamation of them to figure out the best route to go for my scenario:
Instead of pulling the query directly from a file, I created it as a stored procedure in the DB. Then used the Invoke-SQL command in PS to run an EXEC command referencing that stored procedure then used the Export-Csv command to output it into a csv. Then I created a task in task scheduler on the DB server to run this script every day. The downfall to this is every so often I'll have to go in to the script and update a variable manually, but it's much easier than doing this by hand every single day.
Here's the PS invoke command for any future watchers:
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $DB -Username $Username -Password $Password -Query $Query | Export-Csv "C:\TEMP\queryOutput.csv" -Force -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation

